# Comparing data from NSNumber CoreData iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

I've got in CoreData a 
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * hidden;` 
which is Boolean. I am trying using following code
`[object valueForKey:@"hidden"]` 
How can I compare the returned value, to use it in 
`if()`
`if ([[object valueForKey:@"hidden"] isEqualToString:@"1"])` 
doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the bool value of an `NSNumber` using `[[object valueForKey:@"hidden"] boolValue]` and that way you can do proper bool handling.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an NSNumber that you want to treat as a BOOL use...

```
NSNumber *hidden = [object valueForKey:@"hidden"];
if (hidden.boolValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your property 'hidden' is an NSNumber, it's not a string.  Try this instead:

`if([[object valueForKey: @"hidden"] isEqualToNumber: [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]])`

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isOnOrOff = [myEntity.onOrOff boolValue];
```